# Reason for closure in the Reopen Vote review page

Tags: feature-request

I have started reviewing Reopen Votes and there is something I struggle with: the review page does not inform on the reason for closure. The only way to know this seems to be jumping to the question thread itself.

Would it be possible to include this information in the Reopen Vote review page itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it matter? Ultimately, only the question's state when you review it should be the only thing that counts.

- In the case of duplicates, there are three tabs over the question: *Question (revised)*, *Duplicate* and *Revision*, which provide all the information needed.
- In other cases, if it is not unclear, too broad, or otherwise off-topic *as it stands*, vote to reopen.
- If there is relevant content in the comment thread (accessible from the review view, IIRC) then either edit in that content yourself, or drop a comment asking for such an edit.

Honestly, I don't see the point of reopening if I would nominate for closure for any reason (except perhaps being a dupe). If it was closed as unclear, but could now be closed as off-topic, I'd vote to leave closed. So, to reiterate: consider only the question's current state.

Comment: Perfect answer to a good question!  2 upvotes!

Comment: I had not noticed the difference from Duplicates to other cases (I have not reviewed that many Reopen votes). Your procedure helps, but assessments of "unclear" or "too broad" are subjective to some extent and not always differentiable.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I usually see "too broad" as a superset of "unclear".

Comment: It should not be so. "Too abroad" is a clear question that may have many different answers. It can also be a numbers of questions bundled together. But in many cases this it is not easy to differentiate between the two. Especially when the English is not sound enough...